# Rspec - Testing method received call inside another method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In my Rails application I am testing a instance method that sends a SMS message out. It looks like this:

**group.rb**

```
def send_notifications
  twilio_sms = Twilio::REST::Client.new('mykey', 'mykey')
  begin
    twilio_sms.account.messages.create(
          from: "+188888888",
          to: "+1#{phone_number}",
          body: "Message from Company: New item uploaded to group"
    )
  rescue
    puts 'Invalid number'
  end
end
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to test the `twilio_sms.account.messages.create` part.

My spec looks something like this so far:

**group_spec.rb**

```
describe Group do
  context 'instance methods' do
    describe '.send_notifictions' do
      it 'calls the create method on the twilio messages object' do
        twilio_messages = instance_double("Twilio::REST::Messages")
        expect(twilio_messages).to receive(:create)

        group = create(:group_with_notifications)
        group.send_notifications 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This obviously isn't working or I wouldn't be asking this question. What is the proper way to test that the create message was sent properly? Or am I approaching this the wrong way? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
describe Group do
  describe 'instance methods' do

    describe '.send_notifictions' do
      it 'creates a new message' do
        twilio_sms = double(:twilio_sms)
        twilio_messages = double(:twilio_messages)
        expect(Twilio::REST::Client).to receive(:new).with('mykey', 'mykey').and_return(twilio_sms)
        expect(twilio_sms).to receive(:account).and_return(twilio_messages)
        expect(twilio_messages).to receive(:messages).and_return(twilio_messages)
        expect(twilio_messages).to receive(:create).with({:from => "+188888888", :to => "+15555555", :body => "Message from Company: New item uploaded to group"}).and_return(true)
        group = Group.create(some_attributes: 'foo')
        group.send_notifications
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome that worked, thanks. Are the and_return parts actually returning the objects or are they just expecting them to return?

Comment: Took me a long time to figure this out when i was learning this type of testing, the ```and_return``` is actually returning the **altered state of the object**. So it's necessary to put them